# How Unity Generates Cache Hash For AssetBundles

Tags: unity-game-engine, caching, cryptography

I am looking into the technical aspect to how Unity generates the cache name for an asset bundle.

For example, my game caches an asset bundle of `URL`, `Hash128` and `CRC` to a bundle of `Example_Game/b2ee2b99701af83199d653e4` using `WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload`. How does Unity generate the cache's name from this data? (the "b2ee2b99701af83199d653e4" file name).

In summary, what cryptographic algorithm does Unity use internally to generate this hash for the file name, and how can we recreate the hash from this data ourselves?

For reference, the version of Unity I'm using is Unity 4.6 - hence the old `LoadFromCacheOrDownload` method that is being used.